# Stack dumps when turning on Temporal Table SYSTEM_VERSIONING

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I am running SQL Server 2016 SP1 (13.0.4001) on Windows Sever 2012 R2. I have the below table.

```
CREATE TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients](
    [IngredientId] [int] IDENTITY(1,2) NOT NULL,
    [IngredientName] [nvarchar](328) NOT NULL,
    [IngredientShortDescription] [nvarchar](328) NOT NULL,
    [PortionUOMTypeId] [smallint] NULL,
    [WISRTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [WISRSubTypeId] [smallint] NULL,
    [FlavorTypeId] [smallint] NULL,
    [StatusTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [IsMandatory] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDownloaded] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDT] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdateDT] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastUpdateBy] [int] NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DeletedDT] [datetime] NULL,
    [DeletedBy] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedUserName] [nvarchar](136) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedUserName] [nvarchar](136) NULL,
    [DeletedUserName] [nvarchar](136) NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [datetime2](2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [ValidTo] [datetime2](2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Ingredients_IngredientId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IngredientId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY],
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([ValidFrom], [ValidTo])
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Ingredients_IsMandatory]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsMandatory]
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Ingredients_IsDownloaded]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDownloaded]
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Ingredients_Deleted]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Deleted]
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ValidFrom]  DEFAULT (dateadd(second,(-1),sysutcdatetime())) FOR [ValidFrom]
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ValidTo]  DEFAULT ('9999.12.31 23:59:59.99') FOR [ValidTo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Ingredients_TlkpFlavorTypes_FlavorTypeId] FOREIGN KEY([FlavorTypeId])
REFERENCES [SubEx].[TlkpFlavorTypes] ([FlavorTypeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Ingredients_TlkpFlavorTypes_FlavorTypeId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Ingredients_TlkpStatusTypes_StatusTypeId] FOREIGN KEY([StatusTypeId])
REFERENCES [SubEx].[TlkpStatusTypes] ([StatusTypeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Ingredients_TlkpStatusTypes_StatusTypeId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Ingredients_TlkpWISRCategoryTypes_WISRTypeId] FOREIGN KEY([WISRTypeId])
REFERENCES [SubEx].[TlkpWISRCategoryTypes] ([WISRTypeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Ingredients_TlkpWISRCategoryTypes_WISRTypeId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Ingredients_TlkpWISRSubCategoryTypes_WISRSubTypeId] FOREIGN KEY([WISRSubTypeId])
REFERENCES [SubEx].[TlkpWISRSubCategoryTypes] ([WISRSubTypeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [SubEx].[Ingredients] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Ingredients_TlkpWISRSubCategoryTypes_WISRSubTypeId]
GO
```

When I run the below script to enable SYSTEM_VERSIONING for my temporal table, I receive the below error message and a stack dump.

```
ALTER TABLE SubEx.Ingredients
    SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = SubEx.IngredientsHistory));
```

> Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 8 Cannot continue the execution
> because the session is in the kill state.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0,
> Line 8 A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results,
> if any, should be discarded.

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to submit a bug with Microsoft?

Comment: I couldn't run your entire script due to FK errors, but as far as simple system-versioning setup, I could not recreate the problem you're encountering.

Comment: Anytime there is a "Severe error" I would submit a support ticket to Microsoft to properly debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be your problem:

[A dump file is generated when you enable system-versioning on a table in SQL Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3210395/fix-a-dump-file-is-generated-when-you-enable-system-versioning-on-a-table-in-sql-server-2016)

Try installing CU1 of Sql 2016 SP1

Comment: Microsoft is recommending the same thing. I am in the middle of installing and testing now.